# $f(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)f(b) < 0$. Show the existence of $c$ element of $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I believe I should be simply restating this question in with respect to Rolle's Theorem (if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(a) = f(b)$ then there exists $c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $f'(c) = 0$).  BUT the problem states that it is continuous on open interval, not closed, and with $f(a)f(b)$ being a negative number, I can't figure $f(a)$ equaling $f(b)$...AND what clue tells me it IS differentiable other than it is continuous so starting to run in circles  Perhaps just staying in Mean Value Theorem? Or is there  an epsilon/delta method of proving this?

Comment: If $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1;& x \in [a,b)\\ -1;& x =b\end{cases}\text{,}$$ then there is no such $c\in (a,b)$ that $f(c) = 0$.

Comment: @Antoine that ain't continuous.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy it's continuous on (a,b)

Comment: Apologies and in fact yours should be an answer.

Comment: and I'm almost getting it on this example, but its twisting my head on the IVT idea because Antoine's example function isn't a usual function that one would show there must be some point c that crosses the x axis, nor is there a 0 at an endpoint....so I'm baffled a little

Comment: The problem (reflecting the point of the IVT) asks to show the existence of f(c) = 0 and Antoine's example shows the non-existence by f of any c in (a,b) = 0 if f(c) is a constant. I guess I'm too tired to think in reverse... any further explanation would help...

Comment: @MathRaider the problem as stated is flawed

Comment: @ David Peterson  The problem as I stated it? I double checked. I was thinking along f(x) = sin(x): (1/2 pi, 3/2 pi) where there is obvious f(c) = 0 ; c = pi. But Antoine's work confused me. How would you restate it, please, thank you

Comment: perhaps the author of the original problem mistakenly listed f(x) on open interval (a,b) incorrectly, or was author throwing me a curve and I need to follow that curve down this rabbit hole? lol thanks

Comment: I don't pretend to know what the author of the problem meant to write, but I'd treat it as being asked to show if x=2 then x^2=5. i.e. not possible.

Comment: OK thanks...I'll keep chugging...appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the Intermediate Value Theorem: $f(a)f(b)<0$ so either $f(a)>0>f(b)$ or $f(a)<0<f(b)$. In either case, there must be a $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.

**Edit**: the argument here needs $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$. Continuity on $(a,b)$ isn't enough, as Antoine has shown in his comment.

Comment: unless Antoine's example above?

Comment: that's what I am thinking and others here are belabored by this on my behalf and I can't wait to argue this in class tomorrow, so thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: DOH! I forgot that in my fog!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he's trying to prove the intermediate value theorem:

f does'nt have to be differentiable, but the product f(a)*f(b)<0 implies: f(a) and f(b) are of opposite sign. So if there isn't such a c as f(c)=0 on (a,b), then f is of constant sign on it because of its continuity, and there is an absurdity

Comment: by contradiction then?

Comment: that's a way to do it. Prove that f has to be of constant sign and you're good